# Методы защиты от ARP спуфинга

Tags: arp

Как будут работать метода защиты от ARP спуфинга если допустим такая ситуация - в сети 2 PC подключается третий и посылает запрос на определение мак адреса по ip и оба PC ответят ему что это их адреса. Как будет решаться такой конфликт. (если мы не говорим про метод защиты с статической таблицей) И можем допустить даже что злоумышленник прислал ответ раньше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> и оба PC ответят ему что это их адреса.

Чей ответ физически придёт быстрее тот и будет занесён в таблицу, второй пакет будет отброшен. В стандартном протоколе arp для `IPv4` не предусмотрена защита от таких атак. В `IPv6` за место arp используется другой протокол.

Но существует несколько методов защиты согласно википедии:

1. Организация VLAN

   Если в локальной сети есть разделение на несколько VLAN, то атака ARP-spoofing может быть применена только к компьютерам, находящимся в одном VLAN. Идеальной ситуацией, с точки зрения безопасности, является наличие только одного компьютера и интерфейса маршрутизатора в одном VLAN. Атака ARP-spoofing для такого сегмента невозможна.
2. Использование статического ARP

   Можно избежать атаки ARP-spoofing путём настраивания ARP-таблицы вручную. Тогда злоумышленник не сможет обновлять ARP-таблицы путём посылки ARP-ответов на интерфейсы компьютеров.
3. Использование шифрования

   Для предотвращения атаки ARP-spoofing (как и любой атаки «человек посередине») в локальной сети можно использовать протоколы шифрования данных для защиты передаваемой информации от злоумышленника. Например такие протоколы, как PPPoE или IPSec.

Answer (score 1):

+1. `+ на wifi запретить client-client коммуникацию (она идет через ap).

+3. `+ EAPOL 802.1x - поверх эзернета запускается подобие wpa.

4. Запретить arp на управляемом свиче или на точках доступа, кроме направлений к роутеру и от роутера. На роутере включить проксиарп.

Comment: arp использует же BROADCAST, физически пакет может и идёт от клиента к роутеру и на оборот но логически он идёт всем, по этому "Запретить arp на управляемом свиче или на точках доступа, кроме направлений к роутеру и от роутера" только сломает всё.

Comment: ломает -да и одновременно чинится проксиарп

Comment: Т.е вы предлагаете поместить каждого клиента в отдельную сеть и дать возможность посылать arp запросы через proxyarp?

Comment: нет, сеть остается общей в отличие от вланов. будет работать мультикаст и бродкаст, но юникаст будет ходить только через роутер.